# Finding CA Cert from a Synology NAS to use it with curl --cacert

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, synology-diskstation, trusted-root-ca

My Synology uses self-signed certificate, so I need to include it with `curl --cacert /path/to/cert.pem` to connect safely from a terminal to NAS using `https`. How can I find this certificate on my Synology?

`cert.pem` file exported with Synology web interface **'Control panel' > Security > Certificate > action > 'export certificate'** is (probably) not the right certificate.

```
$ curl --cacert /path/to/cert.pem 192.168.1.10
* error setting certificate file: cert.pem
```

Using with ssh:

```
$ sudo find . -name cacert.pem
```

Synology only finds docker paths like ./volume1/@docker/btrfs/subvolumes/.../cecert.pem